# Multiple width flexicolumns

Tags: flexbox

I have been struggling with the flexbox column layout. I am trying to create a 3 column layout that stretch vertically all the way to the end of the page (`height:100%;`). However, 2 of the columns must have specific widths that still scale down on different size screens, is this possible?

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}
.initial {
    -webkit-flex: initial;
    flex: 1;
    width: 510px;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.flex1 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 28px; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    flex-basis: 28px;
}
.flex2 {
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="elem initial">
        <div id="Left">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="elem flex1">
        <div class="col"><img src="img/stripe"/></div>
    </section>

    <section class="elem flex2">
        <div id="Right">
            <h2>Header</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>List item.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a working example](http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/VYJmzR?editors=110) of what you might be looking for, if I've understood the question correct.

I've commented the important stuff in the code. Take a look at the code, and compare it with your own. You've been using some unnecessary flexbox elements such as `flex-basis: 28px;` which should just be `width: 28px;`

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="elem initial">
        <div id="Left">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="elem flex1">
        <div class="col"><img src="img/stripe"/></div>
    </section>

    <section class="elem flex2">
        <div id="Right">
            <h2>Header</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>List item.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* Makes it possible to illustrate the full 100% height */
}
.container {
    display: flex; /* Adds flex functionality */
    height: 100%;
}
.initial {
    width: 510px;
    min-width: 100px;

    background-color: orange;
}

.flex1 {
    width: 28px;

    background-color: red;
}
.flex2 {
    flex: 1; /* Fills the rest of the available space */

    background-color: green;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I forked the pen in order to create a new working example based on the comments from the author of this question. He wanted the columns to wrap and the gutter to disappear at a certain size - I've used media queries to accomplish this.

[Link to the new forked CodePen](http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/dPxape?editors=110)

HTML is the same.

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* Makes it possible to illustrate the full 100% height */
}
.container {
    display: flex; /* Adds flex functionality */
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
.initial {
    width: 510px;
    min-width: 100px;

    background-color: orange;
}

.flex1 {
    display: none;    
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    .flex1 {
        display: flex;
        width: 28px;
        background-color: red;
    }   
}
.flex2 {
    flex: 1; /* Fills the rest of the available space */

    background-color: green;
}
```

Remember your vendor-prefixes.

Comment: Hey many thanks Matias, but is there a reason why I still have to scroll beyond the container/body even if the height is 100%?

Comment: I have also noticed that when the screen resizes, the last flex item does not wrap around

Comment: Yup, I have been spending hours on this now and it will not work. The content does not wrap, there are margins above and below body/html tags. It is not responsive unfortunately.

Comment: You did not state that it needed to wrap in your original question.
The margin is generated by the Codepen editor, add `margin: 0;` to remove it.

Please rephrase your question to fit your exact needs and I will be able to create a better example.

Comment: Hi I had to use another method as I did not have the time to implement this whilst learning it. I will have to look further into the issue but basically I needed one fixed column + 1 fixed gutter and a flexible third column, however, when the screen shrinks I would have needed all columns to wrap around and the gutter to disappear. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi HGB. I've updated the answer with a fork of the original Pen - I've used media queries to give you an example of how you can remove the "gutter" and wrap the columns beneath each other until a certain breakpoint. Please note this is a mobile-first approach - So the elements start out wrapped (in the code) and flow next to eachother after hitting 768px. 
I hope this helps you solve your issues.

Comment: Hi Matias, many thanks for this! It is too late for me to implement it now but  I will definitely make use of it in the future!